# How to escape underscore in string

Tags: regular-expressions, replace

I want to escape a underscore in a filename with a backslash (`\`). So `file_01.jpg` would become `file\_01.jpg`.

I tried:

```el
(replace-regexp-in-string "_" "\_"  "file_01.jpg" t t)
```

but that produces `file_01.jpg`. And:

```el
(replace-regexp-in-string "_" "\\_"  "file_01.jpg" t t)
```

gives `file\\_01.jpg`.

How can I insert a single backslash?

Comment: This possibly isn't the best way to do whatever it is that you need to do. What is it that requires escaped underscores in filenames?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your second example is actually correct.  The resulting string contains a single backslash; it looks like a double backslash because it's printed as an Emacs Lisp string.

You can see this by converting the string into a list of one-character strings:

```
(mapcar 'string (replace-regexp-in-string "_" "\\_" "file_01.jpg" t t))
```

This returns:

```
("f" "i" "l" "e" "\\" "_" "0" "1" "." "j" "p" "g")
```

`"\\"` is a string with one character, a backslash. It is displayed with two backslashes because that's required by Emacs Lisp string syntax.

Comment: The reason I want this is because I'm converting a org document to md with pandoc. The underscore interprets the following 01 as subscript. It works correct if I escape the underscore. "file\\_01.jpg still gives me "file\" and then "01" as underscore. I guess i need something that gives me this list of one-character string: ("f" "i" "l" "e" "\_" "0" "1" "." "j" "p" "g")

Comment: That would be `(mapcar 'string "file_01.jpg")`, if I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: sorry I meant ("f" "i" "l" "e" "\\_" "0" "1" "." "j" "p" "g").

Comment: What should the `"\_"` string contain — a backslash, an underscore, or both?

Comment: both. it should be an escaped underscore.

Comment: That would be written as `"\\_"`.

Comment: this does not work in org. "\\\_" is an escaped backslash following a underscore. what org mode needs is an escaped underscore "\\_". I can get the desired result interactivley in a buffer with replace-string but I need to turn it in a function that puts one (and only one) backlash in front of every underscore in an org buffer.

Comment: OK. I got it. sorry very new in elsip. when I insert the string with the double backslash i get the result i want. thank for your persitance!

Answer (score 0):

Use `(replace-string "_" "\\_")`, maybe in combined `with-temp-buffer` to put the string in.